# Movie where man implants device on his head and gathers children

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie which I saw the trailer for a couple of years ago. Probably from 2009, but maybe later.

It was a science fiction / body horror movie, set in the current time. There was a creepy, driven guy who implanted some kind of device on top of, or into his head. The thing he put on his head was very striking, it looked like an elongated pyramid, or cone. He seemed to live in an abandoned warehouse, and he gathered a lot of kids around him (who he probably controled with his device). Unfortunately, I don't remember more details, because it was just a trailer. It's probably not too obscure, because it ran in a mainstream cinema before a big film (probably Moon), however I can't find it.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is [*X-Men*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(film)).

Comment: If the device was purple, it may be Barney.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The movie is called *[0000](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321135855/http://0000themovie.com/)*. I was looking for the same thing and finally found it.

[image: Image of the man with the device on his head, flanked by kids with their own devices]

You can also view some details at the director's site, http://eddiealcazar.com/

Comment: Wow, thanks! No wonder I didn't find it, 0000 is basically ungooglable.

Comment: While the URL above is now dead (and the project as well, perhaps), you can still find some information about this unreleased film at http://echowolfproductions.com/0000-the-movie/ and at the director's site, http://eddiealcazar.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Pyramid Head](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoR_euZ_e_c) (spoilers) from [Silent Hill (2006)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Hill_%28film%29) had an elongated pyramid for a head.

The time is earlier than you asked for, but the abandoned warehouse, kids, horror, and pyramid head fits.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be The City of Lost Children?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_Of_Lost_Children

Comment: Thanks. There are some simularities, but it is not the same film. The one I'm looking for is definitely from after 2008, and is more realist or near-future sci-fi than fantasy.